# What CMS am I seeing?

Tags: content-management-system

I've noticed several websites carrying a '.do' extension in filenames referenced in the URLs. As you navigate the web of Iberia Airlines, for example, the Spanish state-run airline, you see URLs like http://www.iberia.com/OneToOne/v3/obsmenu.do?prgOid=536886780&tabId=0&menuId=28000000000000&menuRP=1&language=en&country=ES&market=ES&IS_ANONYMOUS=true - I've seen this extension at other websites of very high quality and was wondering what's the software. I wrote CMS in the title but I'm at a loss for what it could be, maybe a framework, maybe something that only runs in an IBM mainframe... don't really know. Looking at the bottom of the pages for any identification yields nothing, no copyright, no company name.

Comment: The .do extension is popular among struts community

Comment: Perhaps you could change the title of the question, so that others who wonder about the same thing can find it?

Comment: Totally OT, but Iberia is not state-run since two decades... http://grupo.iberia.es/portal/site/grupoiberia/menuitem.5dcd178a7f0a73be19736c10d21061ca/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This extension is commonly used by server-side Java platforms like IBM WebSphere.

Comment: Not just Websphere - Anything that uses Servlets.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is going to help, but the `.do` part of obsmenu.do leads me to believe this is a Java based application - you see .do in Java Servlets.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I could have never found out by myself... extension is too meaningless to throw at google.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it was first introduced by [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/) controller mapping. It states for "do" something.

> In the web.xml file, you configure the framework ActionServlet as the servlet that will handle all requests for a given mapping (usually the extension .do is used). The ActionServlet is the "switchboard" mentioned in the opening paragraph. ([Source](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/faqs/works.html))

Nowadays it's commonly used outside of Struts, so there's no way to be sure of which technology is behind the scenes.